# jQuery, Ajax: Unable to replace HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There's a button on a webpage.  When clicked, it will replace paragraph (`<p>`) with header (`<h1>`).

However, I can't seem to make it worked:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <section>
       <p id="replaceableP1">This text will be replaced </p>
       <button id="myButton">Get External Data</button>               
    </section>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $("#myButton").click(function(){             
             $.get("someInfo.html", function (data, status){
                  if (status === "success"){
                      $('#replaceableP1').html(data);
                  } else {
                      $("#replaceableP1").html("Problem reading data");
                  }

              });
         });
});
```

**someInfo.html**

```
<h1>This is external data!</h1>
```

The error generates on: `$('#replaceableP1').html(data);` in the **main.js**

If I replace `data` with `"displayText"`, it will replace element **index.html** and *displayText*.

If I remove **someInfo.html** from the directory, the webpage won't even generate error message: *Problem reading data*.

What's wrong with the code?

***EDIT: My bad, I forgot there is `$("#myButton").click(function(){`***

Comment: Well, for starters you've got one too many closing braces/brackets. Remove the last `});` and see if it works better.

Comment: Well there is no click event, so not sure how the button replaces content.

Comment: The AJAX request is executed as soon as the page is loaded i.e. `$(document).ready`. This works: https://jsbin.com/gucawus/

Comment: @user2789240 could you check on network tab what returns from the call "/someInfo.html", and what error did you get on main.js? could you paste it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that I see. The first is that you have an extra "});" in your main.js file. The second is that .html will replace the inner HTML of the selected element. If you want to replace the `<p>` with the `<h1>`, you would use .replaceWith.

For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("someInfo.html", function(data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            $('#replaceableP1').replaceWith(data);
        } else {
            $("#replaceableP1").html("Problem reading data");
         }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Still error: `Type error: context is null`  Then it points to jquery.js, as well as the line with `$('#replaceableP1').replaceWith(data);`

Comment: Hmmm. There may be other code causing an issue. Here is a Plunker link with the working code... https://plnkr.co/edit/pgdwZM4t8LnDSkAjoGa4?p=preview

Comment: I agree with you.  I think something else in my code is wrong.  Anyway, thanks for answering my question :)  I will try to re-create the whole page again, to see if I can find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
     $.get("Info.html", function (data, status){
          if (status ==="success"){
              $('#replaceableP1').html(data);
          } else {
              $("#replaceableP1").html("Problem reading data");
          }

          });
     });
  });
```

try this and check if js files are loaded or not.